# Docker - Mount docker image's root folder on different Disk

Tags: image, docker, disk

By default when running a docker image its root folder is mounted on dockers installation disk.
Currently Im running low space on the partition where docker is installed.

is it possible to specify that a docker image root disk should consume memory from a different disk?.

I tried putting: 
`DOCKER_OPTS="-g /data/docker` in `/etc/default/docker`

Comment: Setting `-g /data/docker` should work.  Have you restarted Docker after making that change?  If you look at the running `docker` process using `ps`, do you see the `-g /data/docker` parameter?

Comment: yeah, restarting do the trick, now all the images have been re-downloaded and are using the new disk :)